# Why are there hundreds of temp files on my computer as soon as I use the internet?

Tags: windows-xp

I just did a rough count of temp files on my computer using Internet Options/Browsing History/View files and found there are over 200 files in the directory as soon as I connect to the internet. Where do they come from? Is this normal or could it be a malfunction?

Comment: keep in mind, ever image, html/css/js document, and just about everything else your browser shows you, is a file that your system downloaded from a server. Your local system then renders these files together into the image of the page that your browser displays. So browsers work by downloading stuff that is only of temporary value. in the old days, when bandwidth was less available, systems could signifigantly improve performance by caching these page elements (aka Temporary Internet Files).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't remove the temporary files manually or with a tool (for example: ccleaner) they will stay on your computer. The reason they are created is to speed up the process to show a webpage. If you visit a webpage frequently, instead of loading all the pictures and code again, the browser will grab them from your temporary folder. It is much faster compared to downloading them again and again.

Firefox can be set up to delete these files every time you close it (other browsers probably too).

If you have a slow internet connection or limited bandwidth, I would keep those files. They are not harmful.